# Quantum Locking Superconductors on Earth's Magnetic Field

Tags: magnetic-fields, superconductivity, geomagnetism

Is the earth's magnetic field strong enough to hold a quantum locked superconductor, or the superconductor wouldn't be able hold its own weight?

How strong should be the earth's magnetic field to hold quantum locked superconductors?

Comment: I've had this exact same question, I wonder if someone had a massive type II, superconducting disk that was very cold if they would be able to flux pin it against the earth.